# Need to use mathematical induction, I don't think I've proved it right though

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The question is calculate the values up to n=6, and guess an explicit formula where:
$$n = 1,  f(1) = 1\\
n = 2, f(2) = 1\\
n = 3,  \frac{(f(n-1))^2 + f(n-2)}{f(n-1) + f(n-2)}$$

Anytime from 3 onwards, plugging it in, the answers will always spit out 1 as the answer. So I did it up to $f(6)$ and once again got 6. SO I have to guess an explicit formula and then use mathematical induction to prove it.

I guessed the formula to just be $f(n) = n / n$

induction:
$$f(1) = 1 / 1 = 1\\
f(2) = 2 / 2 = 1\\
f(3) = 3 / 3 = 1 $$
and so on.

Is this actual mathematical induction? and if not, what would i have to do for it to be?

Comment: @2012ssohn fixed

Comment: Could the OP please verify that the $f(n-2)$ in the denominator is supposed to be there. The formula before @Bellatrix1106's edit appeared to be $$\frac{(f(n-1))^2 + f(n-2)}{f(n-1)} + f(n-2)$$

Comment: @dxiv yes, the denominator is supposed to be (f(n-1) + g(n-2))

Comment: OK, but I don't see how you would get $f(6)=6$ per "*I did it up to f(6) and once again got 6*".

Answer (score 1):

For induction, you start by proving some "base case." Proceed by assuming your inductive hypothesis to be true for $n$ and showing that it holds for $n+1$

Comment: which is what i did right? my base case is if n = 1, 1 / 1 = 1. then n+ 1 is 2 so 2 /2 = 1. which matches up with the results i'm getting in the actual problem

Comment: For $n=3$, you get $(1^2 + 1)/(1+1) = 2/2 \ne n/n$

Comment: I'm sorry how does 2/2 not equal 1?

Comment: $2/2$ does equal 1. It is not, however, $n/n$. When your $n=3$, your formula gives you $2/2$

Comment: I'm sorry Its just not going through to me. I plugged in n =3 into that big fraction at the top, i do end up with 2/2 and then 2/2 = 1. and my induction formula is simply n / n where f(3) = 3 / 3 in the end i get f(3) = 1, which matches the original answer

Comment: And then you concluded that your formula for $f(n)$ must be $n/n$, which cannot be the case if for $f(3)$ you're arriving at $2/2$

Comment: Oh! so you're saying f(3) must end at f(3) = 3 /3 to equal one. not f(3) end at  2 /2 to equal 1? if that's the case. then can you help me figure out what  the explicit formula could be for this question

Comment: would (n*n) / n work? because it would be 3*3 = 9/3 which equals 3.  and if plugged 3 into the original equaiton. you end up with 1. or does my explicit formula have to equal 1 in the end as well?

Comment: @Jim Try $f(n)=1$. Which is of course exactly the same thing as $f(n) = n/n$ or $f(n) = (n^7 +1)/(n^7+1)$ but it's customary to reduce it to the simplest form.

Comment: @dxiv so f(n) = (n^2 +1)/(n^2 + 1)in itself is an explicit formula I could use and then test as a induction method?

Comment: @Jim $f(n)=1$ is an explicit formula, and it is the simplest one. Note that the formula does *not* have to explicitly include $n$ if in fact $f(n)$ is a constant.

Comment: Also, I would start with your base case as either $n=2$ or $n=3$, since $f(0)$ given to you